# Material UI's RaisedButton causing "Element type is invalide error"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this piece of code

```
import React from 'react'
import { RaisedButton } from 'material-ui'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { TextField } from 'redux-form-material-ui'
import { ACCOUNT_FORM_NAME } from 'constants'
import ProviderDataForm from '../ProviderDataForm/ProviderDataForm'
import classes from './AccountForm.scss'

const AccountForm = ({ account, handleSubmit, submitting }) => (
    <form className={classes.container} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h4>Account</h4>
        <Field name="displayName" component={TextField} />
        <Field name="email" component={TextField} />
        <Field name="avatarUrl" component={TextField} />
        {!!account && !!account.providerAccount && <ProviderDataForm providerAccount={account.providerAccount} />}
        <RaisedButton primary label="Save" type="submit" className={classes.submit} />
    </form>
)

AccountForm.propTypes = {
    account: PropTypes.object,
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
    submitting: PropTypes.bool
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: ACCOUNT_FORM_NAME
})(AccountForm)
```

that cause this error `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.`

I've looked to differents responses for this error but none of them seems to solve my problem

note that it works when I remove `<RaisedButton primary label="Save" type="submit" className={classes.submit} />`

Comment: The error message is telling you that the value "classes.submit" is undefined. It is neither a question nor a possibility, it is the value that is evaluated. Fix your classes import. (verify that there is really a submit class on top level, make sure that this is really the way to invoke custom classes in your starter kit, is there really a AccountForm.scss file on the same level as the import, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing with material-ui v1 with material-ui v0

```
className={classes.submit} works only in v1
```

Refer this page  [Styles-Material ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/styles)

So the proper way to apply the style is

1. Overriding with Inline style

```js
const styles = {
  submit: {
    //styles
  },
};
```

```js
<RaisedButton primary label="Save" type="submit" style={styles.submit} />
```

2. Overriding with CSS Styles

```js
    <RaisedButton primary label="Save" type="submit" className="submit/>
```

```css
.submit{
    //styles
}
```

Refer the [Complex Example of RaisedButton](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button) for additional reference

Answer (score 0):

className={classes.submit} this is invalid.  Class name have to be string (name of class)

Comment: Just to be sure. Have You tried? <RaisedButton primary label="Save" type="submit" className="anyClass" />  where .anyClass is example class, beacuse it works in this way

Comment: that's exactly what i did

Comment: I have almost same in my project and works fine <RaisedButton style={styles.loginButtonStyles}
                              buttonStyle={styles.buttonStyle}
                              primary
                              type="submit"
                              label="Login"
                              className="myClass"/>. Probably reason is in another place

Comment: This is my version of material-ui material-ui@0.20.0. Maybe something has changed there